# AWS transcoder Captions Embedded missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, mp4, captions, closed-captions, amazon-elastic-transcoder

We have a problem with MP4 video containing 5 languages captions embedded.
After transcoding in AWS transcoder, file contains no languages.

I want to keep original captions for languages and converting them into an other format (mov-text, cea-608 or cea-708)

The Job id : 1497397548070-s8ituv

Input Caption :

```
'InputCaptions': {
     'MergePolicy': 'MergeRetain',
     'CaptionSources' : []
}
```

Output Caption :

```
'Captions': {
     'CaptionFormats': [{
           'Format': 'cea-708'
     }]
}
```

1. Is it because the captions of my input file is not in good format mov-text, CEA-608 or CEA-708?
2. Is it the good maneer to create the job for keep original captions and convert them?
3. Is it because of my preset (proprity of Audio or Video) ?

Can you help us ?
Best regard.